# using dynamic linq for inner join in c#

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I'm trying to do "join" using Dynamic LINQ and I can not. The code that gives this error:

```
var dados = (from a in db.Usuario
             join b in db.Pessoa on a.PessoaID equals b.PessoaID
             join c in db.TipoPessoa on b.TipoPessoaID equals c.TipoPessoaID
             join d in db.Sexo on b.SexoID equals d.SexoID)
            .Where("(EmpresaID == " + _EmpresaID + " || EmpresaID == 0) && Apagado == \"N\"")
            .OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord)
            .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .Select("new (ID = a.UsuarioID,Login = a.Login )");
```

However, this code here, not "join" gives no problem.

```
var EspecialidadeMedicaLista = (from lista in db.EspecialidadeMedica
                               .Where("(EmpresaID == " + _EmpresaID + " || EmpresaID == 0) && Apagado == \"N\"")
                               .OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord)
                               .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
                               .Take(pageSize)
                                select lista);
```

What is the secret?

Tks

Comment: What is the text of the error that you get?

Comment: I think "EmpresaID" field is in multiple tables that why code does not recognize it. Use the object of that table i.e. "c.EmpresaID".

Comment: Error from VB:

Error 1 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.Where(System.Linq.IQueryable, string, params object[])' has some invalid arguments M:\C#\ERP\ERP\Controllers\UsuarioController.cs 301 21 ERP
Error 2 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable' M:\C#\ERP\ERP\Controllers\UsuarioController.cs 301 21 ERP

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be cause because of a null result in you joins,maybe it's helpful to check for null before your final select.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
            var dados = from a in db.Usuario
                    join b in db.Pessoa on a.PessoaID equals b.PessoaID
                    join c in db.TipoPessoa on b.TipoPessoaID equals c.TipoPessoaID
                    join d in db.Sexo on b.SexoID equals d.SexoID
                    select new
                    {
                        ID = a.UsuarioID,
                        Login = a.Login,
                        Fixo = a.Fixo,
                        Nome = b.Nome,
                        EmpresaID = a.EmpresaID,
                        Apagado = a.Apagado
                    };
        dados = dados.Where("(EmpresaID == " + _EmpresaID + " || EmpresaID == 0) && Apagado == \"N\"");
        dados = dados.OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord);
        dados = dados.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize);
        dados = dados.Take(pageSize);
```

tks help...